# Case insensitive URL rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the url:

`http://example.com/android`

want to redirect all traffic of

`http://example.com/Android`

`http://example.com/ANDROID`

`http://example.com/Andriod`

etc traffic to

`http://example.com/android`

how to do that

Comment: There's an example for that in the manual: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int / Albeit, in which setting wouldn't you do that at the application level anyway?

Comment: kindly share your tried htaccess rule file in your question, thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried any thing

Comment: `Andriod -> android` is not just case sensitive, it is spelling correction also

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to achieve 2 things:

1. Case ccorrecction
2. Spelling (typo) cocrrection

You may be able to use [`mod_spelling` module of Apache:](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) like this in your site root .htaccess

```sh
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
   CheckSpelling on
   CheckCaseOnly on
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i want to do both things on this particular url only

Comment: We cannot predict all spelling mistake. We can only address few specific cases for a certain URL